# Publishing messages to AMQ in Spring Boot using jmsTemplate Asynchronously

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-jms, jmstemplate

Iam trying to publish messages to AMQ using jmsTemlate in Spring Boot project Asyncronously using below code.

@Async
public void sendMessage(String text, String eventName, long entityPk, String messageId, String messageType, long messageVersion, String destinationQueue) {
if (null != text) {
String pubDate = DeUtils.getCurrentDateInString();
try {

```
            Map messageHeaders = getMessageHeader(messageId, messageType, messageVersion, entityPk, pubDate);
            jmsTemplate.send(destinationQueue, session -> {
                TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
                setMessageProperties(messageHeaders, textMessage);
                textMessage.setText(text);
                return textMessage;
            });
            
            saveToPubTable(messageId, messageType, messageVersion, pubDate, CodeTypeConstants.SUCCESS, text);
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            saveToPubTable(messageId, messageType, messageVersion, pubDate, CodeTypeConstants.FAILURE, text);
        }
        finally{
            log.info("PublishAsyncServiceImpl : finally ");
        }

    }
}
```

When i started my spring boot app ,AMQ broker is up and running.After some time i made AMQ down and trying to publish messages.But control is not coming back from jmsTemplate.send method in above code.its not throwing any exception also.Control is not coming to catch or finally blocks also.Not sure what exactly causing the issue.

Comment: In the code snippet try block is missing, its there in my actual code, its just an typo mistake here

Comment: Did you say you bring the broker down and then the call to `send()` hangs?

Comment: @Fermi-4, Yes you are right

Comment: you can configure property `setReceiveTimeout(long receiveTimeout)` where time is in milliseconds

Comment: @Fermi-4, I believe receivetimeout is used when we are consuming anything .I think it doesn't have anything to do with send .But will give a try

Comment: Ah yes you are right... it may be a different timeout parameter. Have you had any luck yet?

Comment: @Fermi-4, No luck so far.

Comment: I had a similar problem once using a Spring template class for kafka. What happens when you debug/step through that section of code (the lambda)? In particular the `TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();` line - does that give you any issues?

Comment: @Fermi-4 ,control is not going to this line ,it's got stuck at send method line

Comment: Can you step into the send method and see where it hangs?